# Missing values when I export my data frame from R to excel

Tags: r, export, writexl

When I export my dataframe from R to excel the last column ends up with no values in excel. Any suggestions please?

I exported through this code:

```
write_xlsx(X,"/Users/MT/Desktop/Analysis v2/Frequency_aez.xlsx")
```

The structure of my data:

```
dput(aez_frequency[1:2, c(1,11, 12, 13, 14) ])
structure(list(GID = c(143696, 143697), Diff1 = c(0, 0), Diff2 = c(0, 0), Diff3 = c(0, 0), Frequency_AEZ_change = structure(list(GID = c(143696, 143697), Country = c("Abyei", "Abyei"), File_name_1 =c("PRIO_AEZ_FS_1981_2010",  "PRIO_AEZ_FS_1981_2010"), AEZ_1 = c("Tropics, lowland semi-arid", "Tropics, lowland semi-arid"), File_name_2 = c("PRIO_AEZ_FS_2011_2040", "PRIO_AEZ_FS_2011_2040"), AEZ_2 = c("Tropics, lowland semi-arid", "Tropics, lowland semi-arid"), File_name_3 = c("PRIO_AEZ_FS_2041_2070", "PRIO_AEZ_FS_2041_2070"), AEZ_3 = c("Tropics, lowland semi-arid", "Tropics, lowland semi-arid"), File_name_4 = c("PRIO_AEZ_FS_2071_2100", "PRIO_AEZ_FS_2071_2100"), AEZ_4 = c("Tropics, lowland semi-arid", "Tropics, lowland semi-arid"), Diff1 = c(0, 0), Diff2 = c(0, 0), Diff3 = c(0, 0), Frequency_AEZ_change = c(0, 0)), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -2L))), row.names = c(NA, -2L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
```

the last column was computed with tidyverse

```
library(tidyverse)

aez_frequency$Frequency_AEZ_change<-aez_frequency %>% mutate(Frequency_AEZ_change= select(., Diff1:Diff3) %>%
       rowSums(na.rm = TRUE))
```

Thank you !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That is because the code returns a nested dataframe.

Try adding a new column with `rowSums` in this way.

```
library(dplyr)

aez_frequency <- aez_frequency %>% mutate(Frequency_AEZ_change= rowSums(select(., Diff1:Diff3))) 

writexl::write_xlsx(aez_frequency,"/Users/MT/Desktop/Analysis v2/Frequency_aez.xlsx")
```